# Error when trying to upload a file to CKAN: "Failed to get credentials for storage upload. Upload cannot proceed"

Tags: ckan

When trying to upload a file to a dataset in CKAN, I get this error in the web interface:

```
Failed to get credentials for storage upload. Upload cannot proceed
```

Comment: Another varient on that error message is "Unable to authenticate upload"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error is usually caused either by CKAN's FileStore not being setup correctly, or the FileStore's dependencies not being installed correctly. See CKAN's [FileStore and File Uploads](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/filestore.html) documentation.

Make sure that:

- You have `pairtree` installed in your CKAN virtualenv (`pip install pairtree`)
- You have `argparse` installed in your CKAN virtualenv (`pip install argparse`)
- You have the `ofs.impl` and `ofs.storage_dir` options set correctly in the `[app:main]` section of your CKAN ini file, e.g.:

  ```
  ofs.impl = pairtree
  ofs.storage_dir = /mnt/datalocale
  ```
- Make sure that your `ofs.storage_dir` directory exists. Run this command in a shell: `mkdir -p /path/to/your/ofs/storage/dir`.
- Make sure that the operating system user that CKAN runs as (e.g. the user `www-data`, if you are running CKAN with Apache on Ubuntu) has read and write permissions for the `ofs.storage_dir`. For example, if you are running CKAN with Apache on Ubuntu, run these commands in the terminal:

  ```
  sudo chown www-data /path/to/your/ofs/storage_dir
  sudo chmod u+rwx /path/to/your/ofs/storage_dir
  sudo service apache2 restart
  ```

If all of the above fails then ask for help, either using this [CKAN tag on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ckan) or the [ckan-dev mailing list](http://lists.okfn.org/mailman/listinfo/ckan-dev). When posting, it is useful to include:

- What operating system you're using
- What version of CKAN you're using
- How you have deployed CKAN (package install or source install? Apache webserver or paster development install?)
- Your CKAN ini file (with any sensitive details removed)
- Any errors you get from CKAN, either from the terminal where you're running `paster serve ...` or, if you're running CKAN with Apache, from a log file such as `/var/log/apache2/YOURSITE.error.log`. If you can get us a full Python traceback, this is usually the most useful thing.
- The output of the `pip freeze` command when run in your CKAN virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

If the older answer doesn't work out, then there is a chance that you don't have the One other option to check, especially if you don't run CKAN at the root url (/), is whether or not the `ckan.api_url` is set properly. This configuration is not automatically set from `ckan.site_url` (which it should be), and if CKAN is installed on a sub-path, like /ckan/, any API calls that are made from Javascript will fail. An additional configuration to try would be to set `ckan.api_url` to be the same as `ckan.site_url`.