# Can I upload a CSV file directly into datastore through CKAN UI?

Tags: ckan

the first time I installed CKAN 2.2 I added the Filestore extension to upload files. But when I tried to preview, I was getting errors. After following some other posts recommending to use datastore instead (since it's used instead of dataproxy), I reinstalled CKAN 2.2, added Datastore and confirmed that it's working using the read and write tests. This time round I haven't installed Filestore.

Now I'm trying to upload a file as a resource to a dataset through CKAN's UI, so I choose a CSV/JSON file but then the screen responds with "Unable to authenticate upload". Looked through error log files, but nothing really told what was going on.

So my question is, can I upload a file using the UI directly into datastore?

Thanks and Regards,

Noel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two different things here, and you can definitely use both Filestore and Datastore at the same time:

- To automatically add CSV files to the datastore whenever a dataset is created, you can use the [DataPusher](http://datapusher.readthedocs.org) extension. This is a standalone service that runs on the server and uploads new files to the DataStore, regardless of if they were uploaded (via the Filestore) or are hosted somewhere else. (note that the old [datastorer](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-datastorer) (with an extra r) is deprecated and no longer used).
- To fix the errors you are getting when setting up the Filestore, check this answer with tips on what to check: [Error when trying to upload a file to CKAN: "Failed to get credentials for storage upload. Upload cannot proceed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971622/error-when-trying-to-upload-a-file-to-ckan-failed-to-get-credentials-for-stora?rq=1)

Comment: How does the datastorer compares to the datapusher (http://datapusher.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) ?

Comment: @Poli the DataPusher is the currently supported way to go, the datastorer is deprecated. I've updated the answer to reflect this