# CKAN file upload not showing

Tags: ubuntu, ckan

I've installed and setup CKAN on an ubuntu cloud server and everything appears to be working fine but I can't get file uploading enabled.

I have following the documentation on the CKAN website http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/filestore.html#setup-file-uploads and I have everything setup as it asks but I still just get the two options of **'Link to a file'** or **'Link to an API'**

I have checked the dev console within chrome and it's not reporting any JavaScript errors (read some other reports online about this being the cause).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What version of CKAN are you using?

Comment: I install it from the http://packaging.ckan.org/python-ckan_2.1_amd64.deb package so I am assuming it's Ckan 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking at the wrong version of the docs. By default, docs.ckan.org shows you the docs for the latest development version of CKAN. You need the docs for CKAN 2.1. Try this: http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.1.1/filestore.html

If you've followed the 2.1 docs and it still isn't working, see this answer: [Error when trying to upload a file to CKAN: "Failed to get credentials for storage upload. Upload cannot proceed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971622/error-when-trying-to-upload-a-file-to-ckan-failed-to-get-credentials-for-stora/13971623#13971623)

Comment: Hi Sean, yes you're right I was! Unfortunately I have worked through the 2.1.1 docs as well and it's still not working

Comment: Thanks for all your help, in end I was the problem not CKAN! I was editing the development.ini (which I thought was in use as this was what the docs referenced) but I should have been in the production.ini.